# how to grep between 2 txt files

Tags: grep

I have 2 txt files

The 1) txt file is like this :

```
    sequence_id description
    Solyc01g005420.2.1  No description available
    Solyc01g006950.3.1  "31.4 cell.vesicle transport Encodes a syntaxin localized at the plasma membrane (SYR1   Syntaxin Related Protein 1  also known as SYP121    PENETRATION1/PEN1).  SYR1/PEN1 is a member of the SNARE superfamily proteins.  SNARE proteins are involved in cell signaling    vesicle traffic     growth and development.  SYR1/PEN1 functions in positioning anchoring of the KAT1 K+ channel protein at the plasma membrane. Transcription is upregulated by abscisic acid  suggesting a role in ABA signaling.  Also functions in non-host resistance against barley powdery mildew    Blumeria graminis sp. hordei.  SYR1/PEN1 is a nonessential component of the preinvasive resistance against Colletotrichum fungus. Required for mlo resistance. syntaxin of plants 121 (SYP121)"
    Solyc01g007770.2.1  No description available
    Solyc01g008560.3.1  No description available
    Solyc01g068490.3.1  20.1 stress.biotic Encodes a protein containing a U-box and an ARM domain. senescence-associated E3 ubiquitin ligase 1 (SAUL1)
..
.
```

the 2nd txt file has the gene ids:

```
Solyc02g080050.2.1
Solyc09g083200.3.1
Solyc05g050380.3.1
Solyc09g011490.3.1
Solyc04g051490.3.1
Solyc08g006470.3.1
Solyc01g107810.3.1
Solyc03g095770.3.1
Solyc12g006370.2.1
Solyc03g033840.3.1
Solyc02g069250.3.1
Solyc02g077040.3.1
Solyc03g093890.3.1
..
.
.
```

Each txt has a lot more lines than the ones i show. I just wanted to know what grep command should i use that i only get the genes that are on the 2nd txt file, deduct from the 1st with the description next to it.

thanks

Comment: Have you read `man grep`?

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.